# Regular expression to extract hashtags excluding the ones from anchor tags

Tags: javascript

I need to extract #tags from the text editor except for the ones inside anchor tags. The expression I am using currently is:
(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-_]+)

This works fine and shows all matches correctly in the test websites like
https://regex101.com/r/pJ4wC5/57. However when i plugin the same expression its not identifying the ones which are at the beginning of the string.

Edit:
this is the code

```
text=newText.replace(/(?!<a[^>]*?>)(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-_]+)(?![^<]*?<\/a>)/img,function (match,index) {
if(newText[index-1]!=='&'){ 
return '<a  href="" data-hashfilter>' + match + '</a>'
}else{
return match
  }
});
```

I need to capture hash tags preceding with space or start of the string

Comment: Seems like that should work. Can you post the actual code you are using? There may be an issue with that and not the regex.

Comment: Copying the generated code from that website -> https://regex101.com/r/pJ4wC5/57/codegen?language=javascript  and pasting into chrome console works too.

Comment: @mherzig i'm trying to make the match as link

Comment: It still looks OK to me. Open up your browser dev tools, go to the console, and paste `var newText = '#sree This is an #example of some text with #hash-tags - http://www.example.com/#anchor but dont want the link'` (which is your demo text from the regex101 site). Then paste your above code into the console and run that. Then just run `text`. I get the following: `"<a  href="" data-hashfilter>#sree</a> This is an<a  href="" data-hashfilter> #example</a> of some text with<a  href="" data-hashfilter> #hash-tags</a> - http://www.example.com/#anchor but dont want the link"`. Is that not correct?

Comment: thats exactly what i want , some how except for the ones without whitespace (start of string matches) matches are not returned. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired outcome I would deal directly with the elements that need to be checked rather than making a crazy regular expression that has to take into account if the text you are replacing is in a tag or not.

This uses ES6 and `Array.from`. If you need to support non modern browsers you will need to replace the ES6 `function` expressions, `const` and `Array.from` to `Array.prototype.slice.call(arr)`

```js
// get all the elements that need to be searched
const els = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.stuff *'))
// check each elements textContent to see if there is a #hashtag and reduce to an array
const hashTags = els.reduce((hashTags, el) => {
  return hashTags.concat(el.textContent.match(/\#[^\s]+/) || [])
}, [])
console.log(hashTags)
```

```html
<section class="stuff">
  <h3>stuff #heading</h3>
  <p>this is a #paragraph with a <a href="#dontcapture">link with a #hashtag</a></p>
  <p data-hashtag="#hashtag">this has a #datahashtag</p>
</section>
```